# Proving a sequence converges using epsilon-N definition.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, epsilon-delta

[image]

I'm stuck with what to do next in my homework problem please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$Note that for big $j$ you have:

$$4-\frac{2}{j}+\frac{20}{j^2}>3$$

(you can check this) and:

$$1-\frac{6}{j}<\frac{3}{2}$$

So:

$$\left|\frac{1-\frac{6}{j}}{4-\frac{2}{j}+\frac{20}{j^2}}\right|<\frac{\frac{3}{2}}{3}=\frac{1}{2}$$

So for big $j$'s:

$$\frac{1}{j}\left|\frac{1-\frac{6}{j}}{4-\frac{2}{j}+\frac{20}{j^2}}\right|<\frac{1}{j}\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Where did the 3/2 come from?

Comment: Note that $1-\frac{6}{j} \approx 1$ for big $j$. So You can choose any number $>1$, I've chosen $\frac{3}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite 
$$
\frac{j^2+2}{2j^2-j+10} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{{j\over 2} - 3}{2j^2-j+10} $$.
To find an $N(\epsilon)$ that works to prove the limit, a nice trick is to solve for $N$ the equation 
$$
\frac{N^2+2}{2N^2-N+10} = \epsilon
$$
IN the course of solving this, you can always discard terms that make $N$ larger.  You end up with something like 
$$N(\epsilon) = \frac{1}{8\epsilon} + \frac{1}{2} $$

Then you plug that back in and demonstrate that the distance is less than $\epsilon$.